# ln Link is not created when used IFS=read variable for pathname

Tags: symlink, ifs, ln

I want to apply a link to a specific file automatically with a Linux bash script. A part of the target pathname is shall be taken from a txt file. This is my program:

```
bandA="B01"
while IFS= read -r bandB || [ -n "$p" ]
do
  printf '%s\n' $bandA                #from header
  printf '%s\n' $bandB                #from list.txt
  ln -sfn /bst.$bandA.cfg /bst.cfg
done < LIST.txt
```

The first line of LIST.txt is "B01", too. (without quotation marks)

The command line returns always

B01
B01

The problem occurs at the ln command. When I apply $bandA the link is created successfully. When I apply $bandB from the IFS=read the link is not created. Although the variable is obviously written correctly. It must be an issue with the syntax. How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused because some symbols were added during read process:

```
bst."B01'$'\r''.cfg
```

By deleting them with

```
bandB=${bandB//$'\r'/}
```

the link can be created.